# Use a javascript variable in JSP using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page with a form. I want to submit and return the input to the JSP page. I can't get it to work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script> 
        function enviarDatos() {
            form = document.getElementById("datos");
            form.datoIntroducido.value = "holaaaaaa";
            form.submit();

            <%System.out.println(request.getParameter("datoIntroducido"));%>    
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Ejemplo</h3>
    <form name="datos" id="datos" action="mypage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Escribe aquí: </br>
        <textarea cols=50 rows=10 id="texto"></textarea><br />          

        <input type="hidden" name="datoIntroducido" id="datoIntroducido"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos" class="btn-primary" onclick="enviarDatos();"/>
    </form>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It prints "null" when executing the first time but it doesnt write anything when pressing the button

Comment: where do you want to use it in your jsp?

Comment: To pass the `texto` variable to JSP you'd need to use AJAX. If you mean you want to put the `texto` variable somewhere in the page, then you just need to amend the DOM in JS, but you've not defined exactly what you want to do with it.

Comment: You want to update HTML, or send on server side using AJAX?

Comment: if u want to carry over the variable value from one JSP page to another, just set the name of the JSP page in form "action". Then from the second JSP retrieve the value using <% request.getParameter("HTMLelementName")%>. BTW, u don't need "multipart/form-data". It is for file upload.

Comment: I want to send this "texto" on server to use it